# Java Servlet. Catch full OData URL

Tags: java, servlets, odata

I am trying to catch OData call in Java with WebServlet.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;


@WebServlet("/someservice/UserSet")
public class UserSetServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
    protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        //some functionality
   }
}
```

When I call simply "http://somdomain.com/someservice/UserSet", then I get to service, but when I call "http://somdomain.com/someservice/UserSet("SOME_ID")", then I receive 404, that service is not found

Does someone know how I can configure Servlet for catching entire OData Request?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can't you pass `SOME_ID` as a query parameter e.g. `http://somdomain.com/someservice/UserSet?id=SOME_ID`

Comment: No, this is standart OData filtering Format for selecting by ID

Comment: The servlet spec and its derivatives, e.g. JAX-RS, do not support this kind of URLs. JAX-RS accepts regular expressions in the paths, but I do not know to what extent does it cover the OData URL specs. You can do several things: (a) forego the URL spec of OData and use "normal" query/path params (b) write a servlet (or JAX-RS) filter that translates the URI and internally forwards to a resource that uses "normal" query/path params (c) search for an existing framework that does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all answers. Solution - nohow. I starting migration to Spring Framework.